# "Make Mailing Labels" not working for Bosnia language

Tags: pdf, printing

Im trying to "make mailing labels" with contacts with names in Bosnian and CiviCRM cannot create it.

Example:

- Correct: Antolović
- CiviCRM prints: Antolovi?

Instead, CiviCRM shows it correctly in most parts of the CRM, for example
print/merge document in actions of contact summary view.

Any suggestions?

Tx!

Answer (score 3):

It's because it's using Helvetica font which doesn't have unicode characters - if you can use Deja Vu Sans or another font that has unicode it should work.

IGNORE rest of answer below. As per comments Cesar found that under Administer - Communications - Label Formats you can change the font in there.

---

You can try to hack CRM/Utils/PDF/Label.php to hardcode the font: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/5.20.3/CRM/Utils/PDF/Label.php#L180

I'm not sure the right spelling to get the font. If you look in vendor/tecnickcom/tcpdf/fonts/dejavusans.php it seems like it might be `DejaVuSans`, without spaces.

You can also try this instead:

1. Copy vendor/tecnickcom/tcpdf/config/tcpdf_config.php somewhere, e.g.
   /usr/local/tcpdf/tcpdf_config.php
2. Edit the line inside it for PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN so it reads `define('PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN', 'dejavusans');` (again I'm not sure of the exact spelling).
3. In civicrm.settings.php add these lines:

```
define('K_TCPDF_EXTERNAL_CONFIG', TRUE);
require_once('/usr/local/tcpdf/tcpdf_config.php');
```

Comment: Hello, thanks! 

Just now I was trying it, the problem, It does not seem good practice to directly modify the core file, I would like to find a hook that I can access without modifying Label.php

I found this hook but I can't modifying the language:
https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_alterMailingLabelParams/ 

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've updated answer with another thing to try that doesn't involve hacking core. And that hook looks like it only allows modifying certain things but not the font.

Comment: Thanks mate, I found other solution, the admin panel for configure this:
civicrm/admin/labelFormats?reset=1&action=browse 
I think is better solution for this. I hope it helps more people in the future and dont spend more time. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ahh under Communications. I see.

Comment: I made a lab ticket suggesting Deja Vu be the default font for mailing labels: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1502